# View presented from master panel of UISplitViewController not rotating when rotated from portrait to landscape (iPad)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, autorotate

I am presenting a modal view and action sheet from master panel of `UISplitViewController`. `iOS 9.3`

**1)** If I present the view when the iPad is in portrait mode and rotate the iPad to landscape, then the screen is not rotating.[image]
2) But if I present the view when the iPad is in landscape mode and rotate the iPad to portrait, then the screen is rotating.

How can I achieve the rotation?

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions to resolve the issue:

1. It is not ideal to present modal views from master panel but you should be doing it from the UISplitViewController itself.

   ```
   splitViewController.preferredDisplayMode =UISplitViewControllerDisplayModeAllVisible; // For displaying the master panel always as is in the screen shot in the Question
   modalViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet; // For displaying the modalViewController in form sheet style
   [splitViewController presentViewController:modalViewController animated:TRUE completion:nil]; // Note: modalViewController is presented from UISplitViewController and not from master panel of split view
   ```
2. The master panel of spilt view is presented in a popover when in portrait mode so the device rotation changes have to go through popovercontroller. I am guessing the chain breaks at this points. So, to resolve the issue call

   ```
   [spliVC setPreferredDisplayMode:UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryHidden];
   ```

before the modal presentation segue is called(from `prepareForSegue`). I am not sure of whether delegates working with this approach.

**EDIT:**
I have also observed that if the Split view is in `UISplitViewControllerDisplayModeAllVisible` mode then even presenting modal vc from master panel(lets say by a simple modal segue in storyboard) does not give the rotation issue. I have confirmed this in iOS 9.3 simulator.